# HTML generator?

Tags: html, generator

[LESS is very cool](http://lesscss.org/). I always wondered if there are any good html generators that allow me to write a form more easily or do other things. Is there something somewhat similar but for html?

Comment: Hmmm, yes, ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, Ruby on Rails, etc :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/)?

From its website, this Haml code:

```
#profile
  .left.column
    #date= print_date
    #address= current_user.address
  .right.column
    #email= current_user.email
    #bio= current_user.bio
```

gets converted into this HTML.

```
<div id="profile">
  <div class="left column">
    <div id="date"><%= print_date %></div>
    <div id="address"><%= current_user.address %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right column">
    <div id="email"><%= current_user.email %></div>
    <div id="bio"><%= current_user.bio %></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you like Haml, then you might also like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which is Haml for CSS. Actually, [Haml comes with Sass](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Haml). You can still use LESS if you like.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Zen-Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

Uses a CSS style markup to generate HTML with some nice features.

Answer (score 0):

Did one [Blended-HTML On-line Layout Generator](http://www.blended-html.com)
Uses CSS3 and HTML5 markup to generate the source code for HTML page layout on-line.